# Sandbox Apple ID disabled in the App Store and iTunes

Tags: macos, apple-id, mac-appstore, app-store-connect, sandbox

I am attempting to test macOS In-App Purchases via a Sandbox Apple ID.

When I go through the purchase flow, I get the error:

[image]

> #### Your account has been disabled in the App Store and iTunes.
>
> For assistance, contact iTunes Support.
>
> [Environment: Sandbox]

Why was my Apple ID disabled, and how can I use it for this transaction?

Additionally, I now *always* get this error and am unable to sign-in with a different Sandbox account. Is there a way to reset back to a clean slate?